Correct way to swap PyTorch tensors without copying
I have two PyTorch tensors x, y with the same dimensions. I would like to swap the data behind the two tensors, ideally without having to copy. The purpose of this is to have code elsewhere that holds onto the tensor x to now read & write the data y and vice-versa.
What's the correct way to do this? Will this swap potentially break any code that holds onto references to these tensors? Will reference counting/GC for the tensors still work correctly after the swap?

First, you should know that every tensor in PyTorch has an underlying storage that holds its actual data. You can use .storage() to retrieve the underlying storage of a tensor. Then, you should use .set_() to replace the tensor's underlying storage with a new storage.
with torch.no_grad():

    x_storage = x.untyped_storage()
    y_storage = y.untyped_storage()

    x.set_(y_storage, y.storage_offset(), y.size(), y.stride())
    y.set_(x_storage, x.storage_offset(), x.size(), x.stride())

Note: the swapping process does not affect refences to the tensors themselves. Also, swapping the storage does not interfere with the reference counting/GC since PyTorch handles reference counting and garbage collection automatically. Another reason is that you are not creating new tensors or modifying the reference counting directly.
Update
After mentioning in the comments that the swapping will be within an optimizer class, this can potentially affect the autograd graph. Swapping storage objects between tensors, it turns out that the data the autograd graph references is changed. This can lead to inconsistencies between the calculated gradients and the actual computations performed on the swapped tensors. In brief, swapping data directly within an optimizer can be problematic for autograd graph. Therefore, I do not recommend swapping tensors directly within an optimizer class.
The only solution is to use temporary tensors for safe swapping.

Thanks, I'm do a training run now to confirm that it works without breaking anything, should know tomorrow. Will award bounty then.

With PyTorch 2.3.0, this produces a deprecation warning: UserWarning: TypedStorage is deprecated. It will be removed in the future and UntypedStorage will be the only storage class. This should only matter to you if you are using storages directly.  To access UntypedStorage directly, use tensor.untyped_storage() instead of tensor.storage(). Your code will work with untyped_storage() rather than storage() just as well though.

@AaronDefazio , ok you can replace .storage with .untyped_storage(). I modified the answer.

This doesn't work in all cases it seems! I have code using a temporary value to do the swap, using copy_, which works. It's an optimizer class, it swaps the params with another tensor, does some calculations, then swaps back. Plugging in this solution it no longer works. Unclear why, I think there might be a corner case. I get the error message:
0:     return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
0: RuntimeError: mat2 must be a matrix, got 1-D tensor
So maybe it's something to do with views?

@AaronDefazio , ok, I slightly changed the solution by swapping the underlying storage of the tensors without copying their data.

Is using x.size/stride for setting x correct?

@AaronDefazio , yes please check this link: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.set_.html

But shouldn't it bex.set_(y_storage, y.size(), y.stride()) y.set_(x_storage, x.size(), x.stride())

You are right but both have the same dimensions.

It seems that @AaronDefazio tried to improve the swap used by Schedule-Free Optimizer Wrapper:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/schedule_free/blob/main/schedulefree/wrap_schedulefree.py#L107
    @staticmethod
    def swap(x, y):
        # Memory efficient but potentially unstable
        x.add_(y)
        torch.sub(x, y, out=y)
        x.sub_(y)

So I have tested against the example in the repo
https://github.com/facebookresearch/schedule_free/blob/main/examples/mnist/main.py
I made some modification to enable an exact match:
import os
os.environ['CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG'] = ':4096:8' # required to enable deterministic

torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)
...
def main():
    ...
    base_optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr, momentum=0.0)
    optimizer = schedulefree.ScheduleFreeWrapper(
        base_optimizer, momentum=0.9, weight_decay_at_y=0.1)

I found @hamzah-al-qadasi 's method worked -- exactly matched the copy_ implementation.
I tested following 4 implementations and got identical results without any error:
    @staticmethod
    def swap(x: torch.Tensor, y: torch.Tensor):
        t = torch.empty_like(x)
        t.copy_(x)
        x.copy_(y)
        y.copy_(t)

    @staticmethod
    def swap(x: torch.Tensor, y: torch.Tensor):
        t = x.new_empty(())
        t.set_(x)
        x.set_(y)
        y.set_(t)

    @staticmethod
    def swap(x: torch.Tensor, y: torch.Tensor): # Hamzah Al-Qadasi
        x_storage = x.untyped_storage()
        y_storage = y.untyped_storage()
        x.set_(y_storage, y.storage_offset(), y.size(), y.stride())
        y.set_(x_storage, x.storage_offset(), x.size(), x.stride())

    @staticmethod
    def swap(x: torch.Tensor, y: torch.Tensor):
        x.view(torch.uint8).bitwise_xor_(y.view(torch.uint8))
        y.view(torch.uint8).bitwise_xor_(x.view(torch.uint8))
        x.view(torch.uint8).bitwise_xor_(y.view(torch.uint8))


